# Python RSA decryption is throwing error

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.5, private-key, pycrypto

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from base64 import b64decode
def wesocket_Data_Receive(request):
    Data=request.GET.get('ContentData')
    key =open('D:\\WithOldDjango\\AssetManagment\\AssetManagment
    \\blog\\templates\\private.key', 'rb')
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(key.read())
    return HttpResponse(Data)
```

I am getting the following error while reading the private key using python 3.5 error:"RSA key format is not supported"
above is my code

Comment: Well the error message is clear enough. Is `private.key` formatted correctly?

Comment: @Enayath Ali Please show an example private key. Pycrypto usually supports all common key formats.

Comment: iam getting the following error message                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
  File "C:\Users\lstadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 682, in importKey
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported